# Send response when user reacts to a message

Tags: node.js, discord, discord.js

I'm trying to get my first bot up. My aim is to have the bot respond {user.tag} reacted with thumbs up/thumbs down.

I have copied the code from discord.js:

```js
// Require the necessary discord.js classes
const { Client, Intents } = require('discord.js');
const { token } = require('./config.json');

// Create a new client instance
const client = new Client({ intents: [Intents.FLAGS.GUILDS] });

// When the client is ready, run this code (only once)
client.once('ready', () => {
console.log('Ready!');
});

message.react('').then(() => message.react(''));

const filter = (reaction, user) => {
return ['', ''].includes(reaction.emoji.name) && user.id === interaction.user.id;
};

message.awaitReactions({ filter, max: 1, time: 60000, errors: ['time'] })
.then(collected => {
const reaction = collected.first();

        if (reaction.emoji.name === '') {
            message.reply('{user.tag} reacted with a thumbs up.');
        } else {
            message.reply('{user.tag} reacted with a thumbs down.');
        }
    })
    .catch(collected => {
        message.reply('{user.tag} reacted with a different emoji.');
    });

// Login to Discord with your client's token
client.login(token);
```

I get an error:

```
ReferenceError: message is not defined
```

for this line:

`message.react('').then(() => message.react(''));`

How to define 'message?'

I tried:

adding message in:

```js
const filter = (reaction, user, message) => {   return ['', ''].includes(reaction.emoji.name) && user.id === interaction.user.id; };
```

but this creates a compile error.

Comment: Where did you get this code from? Clearly you are using a variable message that has not been initialised.

Answer (score 1):

You need to indicate a trigger in order for the bot to respond to it.

```js
// Require the necessary discord.js classes
const { Client, Intents } = require('discord.js');
const { token } = require('./config.json');

// Create a new client instance
const client = new Client({ intents: [Intents.FLAGS.GUILDS] });

// When the client is ready, run this code (only once)
client.once('ready', () => {
console.log('Ready!');
});

client.on('messageCreate', async message => {
    message.react('').then(() => message.react(''));

//    const filter = (reaction, user) => {
//    return ['', ''].includes(reaction.emoji.name) && user.id === interaction.user.id;
//    };
// Not sure where you are getting interaction from

    const filter = (reaction, user) => user.id == message.author.id && (reaction.emoji.name == '' || reaction.emoji.name == '')

    message.awaitReactions({ filter, max: 1, time: 60000, errors: ['time'] })
    .then(collected => {
        const reaction = collected.first();

        if (reaction.emoji.name === '') {
            message.reply('{user.tag} reacted with a thumbs up.');
        } else {
            message.reply('{user.tag} reacted with a thumbs down.');
        }
    })
    .catch(collected => {
        message.reply('{user.tag} reacted with a different emoji.');
    });
})

// Login to Discord with your client's token
client.login(token);
```